# Retag request: APC (Alternate PHP Cache) and APC (American Power Conversion) the power supplies.

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

There are lots of questions about uninterruptible power supplies that are <del>improperly</del> tagged as [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc)

There also questions about web application performance and the [Pecl PHP opcode caching](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) package, [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), tagged as [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc)

I'm suggesting a new tag [php-apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php-apc) then do a merge and create another new tag [apc-ups](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc-ups)

Comment: I would think we'd want `php-apc` instead of the other way around.

Comment: Makes more sense.  I'm editing.

Comment: Huh, never knew about alternate-php-cache, probably because I have [php] suppressed!

Comment: @sysadmin don't worry i'd never heard of it either and I _don't_ have [php] suppressed.

Answer (score 10):

There are 95 questions tagged [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc)

[apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) + [php](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php) = 51 also [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) + question contains php = 67.

[apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) + [ups](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ups) = 15.

Suggestion

Retag questions tagged [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) + [ups](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ups) to [apc-ups](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc-ups) 
Retag questions tagged [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) + question contains php to [php-apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php-apc)

Manually retag the 13 remaining questions.

Synonym or delete [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) ? **Blackhole APC**

Comment: I further point out that APC is a company, not a product, so [aps-ups] make a lot of sense, as would [apc-pdu] and the like.

Comment: Best option then delete and ban apc.

Comment: I'd nuke [APC] as a tag personally - It will be re-populated with this same kind of confusion (as well as gathering every APC PDU, UPS, etc. question under the sun)

Comment: ok apc is nuked @vore

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll find that when a system administrator mentions APC it's automatically assumed we're taking about a UPS, not a rather minor bit of software. Your statement that "questions about uninterruptible power supplies that are improperly tagged as apc" makes no sense. To put it simply, you've got it back to front and questions about "Alternative PHP Cache" are incorrectly tagged and may well be off topic to boot.

Comment: Good point.  Either way the decision and division needs to be clarified.

Comment: I don't think PHP-APC is off-topic.  Since properly configuring and tuning a web server is something a sysadmin would be doing.

Comment: +1 - I don't know about PHP-APC being off topic, but APC UPS questions are certainly on-topic and in my experience more likely...

Answer (score 0):

APC makes more than just UPS devices.  I would submit using apc-ups is overly narrow.

Comment: See sysadmin1138's comment to my answer.

Comment: Yup, upvoted his comment.