# What happened to the apc tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

A few months back I [asked about a retag-request for the apc tag](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1543/51946) because of the confusion between the PHP APC opcode cache and APC meaning American Power Systems backup power supplies.

I just noticed that the [apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apc) tag was removed from [all the questions](https://serverfault.com/search?page=4&tab=relevance&q=apc) without an alternative tag.

I think [php-apc](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php-apc) would be a useful tag especially since there is such a history of questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

It needs someone to go through and retag questions appropriately.

Since there's so many, best to do on the weekend.